# code: 400 error when trying to insert a new permission using Google Drive API v2

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using google-api-client (0.3.0) gem for my Rails app to access a user's data through Google Drive API v2.

I successfully searched for a file by title and then tried to use the file id from the search result to insert a new permission. I want to programmatically allow "anyone with the link" to comment on the file.

Following the sample code here:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert, I wrote the following code:

```
new_permission = gDriveApi.permissions.insert.request_schema.new({ 
                         'role' => "reader",
                         'type' => "anyone",
                         'value' => "",
                         'additionalRoles' => ["commenter"], 
                         'withLink' => true })

result = client.execute(:api_method => gDriveApi.permissions.insert,
                        :body_object => new_permission,
                        :parameters => { 'fileId' => file_id })
```

I got a 400 error. Here is the hash dump:

```
--- !ruby/object:Google::APIClient::Schema::Drive::V2::Permission 
data: 
  error: 
    errors: 
    - domain: global reason: parseError 
      message: This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.
    code: 400 
    message: This API does not support parsing form-encoded input.
```

According to errors.rb in the gem source code, a 4xx error is a client error.

Any help fixing this bug would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not proficient in Ruby but perhaps you could log the HTTP request to see what is happening. For now it seems like a bug in the client library though, unless there ia way to configure it to perform form-encoded posts vs JSON posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely an issue in that version of the client library and there were significant changes between 0.3 and 0.4. I ran the same snippet on the current version 0.4.4 and it worked fine. Suggest updating your dependency if at all possible.

Comment: Updating google-api-client gem to 0.4.3 fixed the problem. Thanks very much, Steve!